# Does Ubuntu still brick certain devices?

Tags: installation, 13.04, uefi

I read previously on other threads that installing ubuntu on some newer machines can cause the problems with the bios, where 'Ubuntu' will write over the bios, and cause the machine to end up being a brick.

How do I know if I'm safe?

Comment: Please be more specific on how Ubuntu would brick a PC. Provide a link to this source for example. As your question now stands it's not really supported by any facts.

Answer (score 3):

You're getting a bit mislead here.

The problem [was with certain systems that use UEFI](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-cdimage/+bug/1040557). It has since been solved. Other systems were (and remain) unaffected. So, if your system isn't from Samsung and doesn't come with Windows 8, you're likely in the clear.

Comment: Good translation.. that said, I wouldn't classify it as 'bricking' the system.  There's almost always a way (albeit difficult for some new users) to correct the overwrites in the end.

Comment: Keep in mind, you can do a lot of damage from a live CD. IMO, most "bricked" systems result when new users deviate from the installer defaults without reading what they are doing. Sometimes Ubuntu can damage windows, especially when resizing the windows partition. It should NOT touch the BIOS, although again changing the BIOS settings to enable Ubuntu to boot can prevent windows from booting. I thing the bottom line is that installations can fail for a variety of reasons, new users should be encouraged to read and back up, and experienced users should assist and bebunk FUD

Comment: @bodhi.zazen no offence, but was that really necessary for this particular situation :)?

Comment: @RolandiXor I was not trying to stir the pot, but if the comment is off topic I can remove it.