# Can i install Ubuntu 13.04 on a Samsung NP355V5C (Windows 8 preinstalled) laptop?

Tags: installation, 13.04, uefi, samsung

I heard that installing Ubuntu on some Samsung laptops with a preinstalled Windows 8 and a UEFI Bios can crash them.
I want to install Ubuntu 13.04 on my Samsung NP355V5C, but i'm not sure if it will crash my laptop too, so i wanted to ask here, just to be sure. 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been worked around in recent kernels; however, I'm not sure of the state of the kernel that Ubuntu 13.04 will install initially, so at the very least, you should *immediately* upgrade your kernel to the latest version.

This problem has been getting a lot of coverage here lately, but because the issue is fast-changing, older answers may be inaccurate. Some relatively recent ones are:

- [Is it safe to install Ubuntu 64 Bit 12.10 in EFI mode on Samsung series 7 WIndows 8 laptop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270036/is-it-safe-to-install-ubuntu-64-bit-12-10-in-efi-mode-on-samsung-series-7-window)
- [Ubuntu on Samsung Series 5](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307371/ubuntu-on-samsung-series-5)
- [Does Ubuntu still brick certain devices?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298714/does-ubuntu-still-brick-certain-devices)
- [Can't boot Ubuntu or Windows 8 after Ubuntu 64-bit install on Samsung series 7 Windows 8 laptop, error "All boot options are tried."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/329164/cant-boot-ubuntu-or-windows-8-after-ubuntu-13-04-64-bit-install-on-samsung-seri)